# Form validation error messages without moving input fields

Tags: javascript, css, forms, validation

I need help with form validation.  I would like for the error messages to not move the entire input field when they show up.  This way, I can put them on my @media queries without them moving down and taking up another section below the ones they belong on.  I have tried to add margins beneath the input fields but that doesn't work, it just increases the space between the input fields.  Is there a work around here?  I have just learned this JS yesterday.

Here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/drxl/pen/WNpVQaQ

```html
    <form action="" method="POST" id="contact-form" class="contact">
        <div class="name-form">
          <label for="name">Your Name</label>
          <input  id="name" type="text" placeholder=" Your name..." required>
        </div>

        <div class="email-form">
          <label for="email">Your Email</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder=" Your email..." required>

        </div>
        <div class="contact__txtarea">
          <label for="text">Message</label>
          <textarea class="textarea" id="text" placeholder=" Your message here..." required></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="btn">
          <input class="contact-section__btn" type="submit" value="Send Message" required>
        </div>
      </form>
```

```css
    label {
        display: none;
        font-size: 1px;
    }
    input:-webkit-autofill,
    input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
    input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
    input:-webkit-autofill:active {
        -webkit-transition: "color 9999s ease-out, background-color 9999s ease-out";
        -webkit-transition-delay: 9999s;
    }
    .contact input,
    .contact textarea {
      margin: .5rem;
      font-weight: 1000;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
    
    
    .name-form label,
    .email-form label,
    .contact__textarea label {
      display: none;
    }
    
    input[type="text"],
    [type="email"],
    textarea {
      background-color: rgb(223, 198, 182, 0.875);
      border-color: rgb(201, 83, 5);
      width: 550px;
      height: 40px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(36, 36, 36) 10px 10px 10px;
              box-shadow: rgb(36, 36, 36) 10px 10px 10px;
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: black;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {
      color: black;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: black;
    }
    ::-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: black;
    }
    ::placeholder {
      color: black;
    }
    
    .name-form,
    .email-form,
    .contact__txtarea {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .contact__txtarea label,
    .textarea {
      width: 550px;
      height: 300px;
      vertical-align: top;
    
    }
    
    .error-message {
      color: red;
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
    
    .contact-section__btn {
      padding: 12px 52px;
      background:  rgb(201, 83, 5);
      border: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1rem;
      margin-right: 200rem;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    
    .contact-section__btn:hover,
    .contact-section__btn:focus {
      background-color: rgb(209, 179, 124, 0.7);
      opacity: .7;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(0.85);
      transition: ease .45s;
      margin: 12px;
    }
```

```js
(function() {
      let form = document.querySelector('#contact-form');
      let nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
      let emailInput = document.querySelector('#email');
      let textAreaInput = document.querySelector('#text');
    
      function showErrorMessage(input, message) {
        let container = input.parentElement;
        let error = container.querySelector('.error-message');
        if (error) {
          container.removeChild(error);
        }
    
        if (message) {
          let error = document.createElement('div')
          error.classList.add('error-message');
          error.innerText = message;
          container.appendChild(error);
        }
      }
    
      function validateName() {
        let value = nameInput.value;
        if(!value) {
          showErrorMessage(nameInput, 'Name is a required field.');
          return false;
        }
        showErrorMessage(nameInput, null);
        return true;
      }
    
      function validateEmail() {
        let value = emailInput.value;
        if (!value) {
          showErrorMessage(emailInput, 'Email is a required field.');
          return false;
        }
        if (value.indexOf('@') === -1) {
          showErrorMessage(emailInput, 'You must enter a valid email address.');
          return false;
        }
        showErrorMessage(emailInput, null);
        return true; 
      } 
    
      function validateTextArea() {
        let value = textAreaInput.value;
        if (!value) {
          showErrorMessage(textAreaInput, 'You must enter a message.');
          return false;
        }
        showErrorMessage(textAreaInput, null);
        return true;
      }
    
      function validateForm() {
        let isValidName = validateName;
        let isValidEmail = validateEmail;
        let isValidTextArea = validateTextArea;
        return isValidName && isValidEmail && isValidTextArea;
      }
    
      form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validateForm()) {
          alert('Success!');
        }
      });
    
      nameInput.addEventListener('input', validateName);
      emailInput.addEventListener('input', validateEmail);
      textAreaInput.addEventListener('input', validateTextArea);
    })();
```

Comment: You're adding HTML to the page, so there has to be a layout shift. You can avoid this by including the error divs in the original markup. Then use JS to update the content of the error message, and also use CSS to set `opacity:0` when there's nothing to show, and `opacity:1` when there is an error to show.

Comment: I'm gonna need code I have no idea how to do this on my own.  I am a noob at JS

Comment: Here, https://jsfiddle.net/0gj7mqz2/2/, I only did the first field. Basically, the error message is there the whole time, and we just hide/show it when needed. Since it exists the whole time, there's no layout shift when we hide/show it.